# Issue in mean square error plot

Tags: matlab, implementation

There are 2 column vectors A,B containing 100 data values. I intend to plot the MSE(mean square error ) using the following code but all I get is a single dot instead of a line plot. Please help how to go about it.

```
A=x(:,1);
B=y(:,1);

er=(double(A)-double(B)).^2;
row_er=mean(er,2); % variable changed
plot(row_er);
```

Comment: it works fine for me. Check the size both of x and y.

Answer (score 0):

This script works fine.

```
A = randn(10, 1);
B = randn(10, 1);
er=(double(A)-double(B)).^2;
row_e=mean(er,2);
plot(row_e)
```

Probably you have a typo (`row_er`)

```
row_e=mean(er,2);
plot(row_er);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply,but the typo was here in this forum not in the actual program!! I ran your code as well and it still plots a dot instead of a line plot.Is the logic correct for plotting the mean square error?

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that the command mean returns the mean of a vector (which is one simple value). If you want to plot plot the square error then you just plot((A-B).^2).

But... If you are interested in plotting the mean square error with, say, 10 samples average, you will have a plot with only 10 points (100 / 10 because each 10 data points are averaged to give you one point).

The command would be

plot(blkproc((A-B).^2,[10,1],'mean'))

hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However,it returns an error >>parse inputs Invalid block function. BLOCKPROC returns the user function,FUN to be a valid function handler.

Comment: Also,it is not doing what it is expected to do.Since the data is a single column vector,mean would result in a single value.Issuing the command plot((A-B).^2) plots series of vertical lines with Y axis ranging from 0-1 and X axis till 100.Do not know how to go about this.

Comment: The command is not blockproc, it is its older version blkproc. the first takes handles @mean and the second uses eval so it takes strings.